# Using TFS api to execute(pass/fail) test cases?

Tags: c#, tfs, microsoft-test-manager, testautomationfx

I am currently working on a program to execute test cases in a program, and I have looked at [How to create a test run and result using the Team Foundation Server API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505812/how-to-create-a-test-run-and-result-using-the-team-foundation-server-api) as well as various other articles and am still having lots of trouble. My goal is to locate a test case with a certain title and configuration, execute it and add notes if it failed. Here is just some code I have been messing around with

```
        String server = "http://tfs.net:8080/tfs";
        String project = "Project";
        // Connect to the TeamFoundationServer.
        Console.Write("Connecting to Team Foundation Server {0}...\n", server);

        TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(server));
        Console.WriteLine("Success!\n");
        Console.WriteLine("getting project {0}...\n", project);

        ITestManagementTeamProject teamProject = projectCollection.GetService<ITestManagementService>().GetTeamProject(project);

        Console.WriteLine("Success!\nGetting test cases...\n\n");
        IEnumerable<ITestCase> testCases = teamProject.TestCases.Query("SELECT [Title] FROM WorkItems WHERE State = 'Ready' AND Title CONTAINS 'Phase 1: test case title'");
        foreach (ITestCase t in testCases)
            Console.WriteLine(t.Title);
        ITestSuiteCollection suites = teamProject.TestSuites.Query("SELECT * FROM TestSuite");



        ITestConfigurationCollection configs = teamProject.TestConfigurations.Query("Select * FROM TestConfiguration WHERE Name='Mainline Android Phone 2.3'");
        ITestConfiguration config = configs[0];

        ITestPlan plan = teamProject.TestPlans.Create();
        plan.Name = "herpa derp";

        ITestSuiteBase suite = teamProject.TestSuites.Find(606);


        Console.WriteLine(plan.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(suite.Title);
        plan.RootSuite.Entries.Add(suite);//Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        plan.Save();

        suite.TestCases.AddCases(testCases);
        plan.Save();

        ITestRun run = plan.CreateTestRun(false);


        ITestPointCollection points = plan.QueryTestPoints("SELECT * FROM TestPoint");
        foreach (ITestPoint p in points)
        {
            run.AddTestPoint(p, null);
        }
        run.Save();
        ITestCaseResult result = run.QueryResults()[0];
        result.Outcome = TestOutcome.Passed;
        result.Save();

        //wait dood
        Console.Read();
```

`plan.RootSuite.Entries.Add(suite);`
that is the line where I get the error "nullreferenceexception was unhandled" it's the suite, but the object looks fine. Please let me know if you can help :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might not have proper access to the teamProject in order to view all fields required to pass it to the plan.