# TFS 2012 API : Unable to add Test Point to Test run

Tags: tfs-sdk

I'm trying to use the TFS API to update test results from automation run separately. I've tried the suggestions from other questions here (particularly [How to create a test run and result using the Team Foundation Server API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505812/how-to-create-a-test-run-and-result-using-the-team-foundation-server-api)) as well as from searches elsewhere. No matter what I try I have the same problem: every time I try to add a test point to a test run, I receive the error -

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementInvalidOperationException: This test run cannot be created with the test points.
```

The test points are retrieved from TFS using WIQL, and I check each test point to ensure that it is correct for the test plan, test suite, and test configuration before I attempt to add it.

I can't save the test run without test points.

Sample code (I've gone through so many attempts that my code is now beyond messy)

```
    public void UpdateTests(TestSuiteRun suiteRun)
    {


        this.Config = FindConfig(suiteRun.Description);
        this.Suite = FindSuite(suiteRun.Name); 
        this.Plan = Suite.Plan;
        this.Points = FindPoints(this.Suite.Id, this.Config.Id);
        ITestCaseCollection testCases = Suite.AllTestCases;
        this.Run = TeamProject.TestRuns.Create();
        ConfigureTestRun(); // failing here

        this.Result = CreateRunResults();

        this.Iteration = CreateSingleIteration(suiteRun.Description);
        {
            UpdateResultsForScenario(scen);
        }


     }
```

And the method to configure the test run:

```
    private void ConfigureTestRun()
    {
        this.Run.DateStarted = DateTime.Now;
        this.Run.DateCompleted = DateTime.Now;
        // find the points that correspond to test cases in the run suite
        foreach (ITestPoint point in this.Points)
        {
            if (point.TestCaseExists && point.Plan.Id == this.Plan.Id && point.ConfigurationId == this.Config.Id)
            {
                this.Run.AddTestPoint(point, this.CurrentUser); // fails with InvalidOperationException
            }
        }

        this.Run.Save();
    }
```

I'm able to connect to TFS and retrieve all the data I need but adding test points to a new test run is driving me crazy.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: What does "Save" return, if it's a Bool, what's the result?

Comment: @DaveShaw I'm not getting to "Save" - the routine fails on Run.AddTestPoint().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an insane amount of experimenting and beating my head against the wall, I've found the answer.

For those who are curious, here's how it works:

- If I create the test run using 
  `ITestManagementService.TestRuns.Create();` I can add Test Cases but
  not Test Points.
- If I create the test run using 
  `ITestPlan.CreateTestRun(isAutomated);` I can add Test Points but not
  Test Cases.

I overcomplicated things a lot trying to get this working - I've now cleaned up a lot of the mess and have my application correctly reporting test results to TFS.

I'm using a fake build more or less as described by [Jason Prickett's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2010/02/23/creating-fake-builds-in-tfs-build-2010.aspx).

One thing I did find was that I couldn't define the run as an automated run because I have no test run controllers in my environment and couldn't find a way to move the test run state from WaitingForController to Completed.

There's more cleanup to go but the core works this way:

```
        this.Run = this.Plan.CreateTestRun(false);
        ConfigureTestRun(build);

        this.Result = CreateRunResults();

        this.Iteration = CreateSingleIteration(suiteRun.Description);

// custom processing omitted for brevity

        this.Result.Iterations.Add(this.Iteration);
        // Attach the run log to the results
        ITestAttachment item = this.Iteration.CreateAttachment(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFile"], SourceFileAction.None);
        this.Result.State = TestResultState.Completed;
        this.Result.Save();
        this.Run.Attachments.Add(item);
        this.Run.Save();
```

And the test run configuration routine is:

```
    private void ConfigureTestRun(IBuildDetail build)
    {
        this.Run.DateStarted = DateTime.Now;
        this.Run.DateCompleted = DateTime.Now;
        this.Run.BuildDirectory = build.DropLocation;
        this.Run.BuildFlavor = "debug";
        this.Run.BuildNumber = build.BuildNumber;
        this.Run.BuildPlatform = "test platform";
        this.Run.BuildUri = build.Uri;
        this.Run.Controller = build.BuildController.Name;


        // find the points that correspond to test cases in the run suite
        foreach (ITestPoint point in this.Points)
        {
            if (point.TestCaseExists && point.Plan.Id == this.Plan.Id && point.ConfigurationId == this.Config.Id)
            {
                this.Run.AddTestPoint(point, this.CurrentUser);
            }
        }

        this.Run.Save();
    }
```