# TFS Api - trigger test run conditionally (when new files come)

Tags: testing, tfs, automated-tests, mtm

I'm trying to get acquainted with test automation using Microsoft TFS Api.

I've created the program which runs my test set - it uses code similar to [one described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505812/how-to-create-a-test-run-and-result-using-the-team-foundation-server-api), e.g.:

```
var testRun = _testPoint.Plan.CreateTestRun(false);
testRun.DateStarted = DateTime.Now;
// ...
testRun.Save();
```

I believe this forces them to start as soon as any of agents can run them, instead of being delayed to certain time. Am I wrong? Anyway, it works all right.

But I was told by my lead that the task should be started each time the new input files are copied to certain folder (on the network I think, or perhaps in TFS).

So I'm searching for a way which allow to trigger tests on some condition - but currently without any luck. Probably I miss proper keywords.

I only found something vaguely related [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b31488d7-6527-46f9-9e96-5ca5588d83e7/mtm-conditional-automation-script-execution?forum=vsmantest) but it seems they say it is not possible in a proper way.

So are there any facilities in TFS / MTM, any ways or approaches to achieve my goal? Thanks in advance for any hints / links.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a system service (or other) that uses the file system watcher. Then when the file changes you can run your code above.

There is no built in feature in TFS to watch a folder for changes.