# Pass test case in tfs using tfs api

Tags: c#, tfs

i have the below code to pass the test case in TFS/MTM.I have achieved to pass the test case from outside but when i check the inside steps of the test case,they are not passed.I am looking to pass the test case by passing each action of test case.
any help appreciated.

```
ITestPlan tp = testinsuitesd.Plan;
// foreach (ITestCase testcase in allTestCases)
//{

ITestRun testRun = testinsuitesd.Plan.CreateTestRun(false);
ITestPointCollection testPoints = tp.QueryTestPoints("select * from TestPoint where suiteId= "+ testinsuitesd.Id);
    foreach(ITestPoint testRuns in testPoints)
    {
        testRun.AddTestPoint(testRuns, null);
    }
    testRun.Save();

    ITestCaseResultCollection testCaseResult = testRun.QueryResults();     //code to Pass the test Case
    foreach (ITestCaseResult testResult in testCaseResult)
        {
    ITestIterationResult iterationResult;
   ITestActionResult actionResults;                                   
      iterationResult = testResult.CreateIteration(1);
    //actionResults = testResult.CreateIteration(1);
            foreach (ITestAction testStep in testResult.GetTestCase().Actions)
            {

                ITestActionResult stepResult = iterationResult.CreateStepResult(testStep.Id);                                                    
                //stepResult.ErrorMessage = String.Empty;                                            
                stepResult.Outcome = TestOutcome.Passed; //you can assign different states here

                iterationResult.Actions.Add(stepResult);
        //actionResults.Add(stepResult);
             //   iterationResult.Actions.Add(stepResult);
       // actionResults.   Add(stepResult);
            }

            iterationResult.Outcome = TestOutcome.Passed;                                        
            testResult.Iterations.Add(iterationResult);
    testResult.Outcome = TestOutcome.Passed;
    testResult.State = TestResultState.Completed;
    testResult.Save();
        }
    testCaseResult.Save(false);
//  testCaseResult.
    testRun.Save();
    testRun.Refresh();

tp.Save();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with below code:

```
var tfsRun = _testPoint.Plan.CreateTestRun(false);

tfsRun.DateStarted = DateTime.Now;
tfsRun.AddTestPoint(_testPoint, _currentIdentity);
tfsRun.DateCompleted = DateTime.Now;
tfsRun.Save(); // so results object is created

var result = tfsRun.QueryResults()[0];
result.Owner = _currentIdentity;
result.RunBy = _currentIdentity;
result.State = TestResultState.Completed;
result.DateStarted = DateTime.Now;
result.Duration = new TimeSpan(0L);
result.DateCompleted = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(0.0);

var iteration = result.CreateIteration(1);
iteration.DateStarted = DateTime.Now;
iteration.DateCompleted = DateTime.Now;
iteration.Duration = new TimeSpan(0L);
iteration.Comment = "Run from TFS Test Steps Editor by " + _currentIdentity.DisplayName;

for (int actionIndex = 0; actionIndex < _testEditInfo.TestCase.Actions.Count; actionIndex++)
{
    var testAction = _testEditInfo.TestCase.Actions[actionIndex];
    if (testAction is ISharedStepReference)
        continue;

    var userStep = _testEditInfo.SimpleSteps[actionIndex];

    var stepResult = iteration.CreateStepResult(testAction.Id);
    stepResult.ErrorMessage = String.Empty;
    stepResult.Outcome = userStep.Outcome;

    foreach (var attachmentPath in userStep.AttachmentPaths)
    {
        var attachment = stepResult.CreateAttachment(attachmentPath);
        stepResult.Attachments.Add(attachment);
    }

    iteration.Actions.Add(stepResult);
}

var overallOutcome = _testEditInfo.SimpleSteps.Any(s => s.Outcome != TestOutcome.Passed)
    ? TestOutcome.Failed
    : TestOutcome.Passed;

iteration.Outcome = overallOutcome;

result.Iterations.Add(iteration);

result.Outcome = overallOutcome;
result.Save(false);
```

Moreover, there are also some links about TFS API that may help you:

- [Code snippets on Test Management APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aseemb/2012/08/06/code-snippets-on-test-management-apis/)
- [Test case result using TFS API](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/94cfc7ed-37d9-4c52-966b-b42a618cf20a/test-case-result-using-tfs-api?forum=vsmantest)
- [MTM Testing Scorecard using TFS API](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/10/02/mtm-testing-scorecard-using-tfs-api.aspx)
- [How to create a test run and result using the Team Foundation Server API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505812/how-to-create-a-test-run-and-result-using-the-team-foundation-server-api)

Comment: hi the object used above "_testEditInfo" is of type?Can you please let me know whats the problem with my code.